# Why does SUBSTITUTE function in both Google Spreadsheets and Excel only replace the odd results?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, substitution

So, I'm using Excel as a query builder (lots of us have been there), but I have a problem. Some of the columns, which have empty data, have to be inserted as NULL, so the cleanest way to do this that occurred to me was to use the SUBSTITUTE formula to find those empty spots and change them for NULLs.

This is what I have, as an example:

```
INSERT INTO blah (meh1, meh2, meh3, meh4, meh5, meh6) VALUES (14, '', '', '', '', 5)
```

And this is the formula I use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(*cell*;", ,";", NULL,")
```

This, in my head, should change all the appearances of ", ," to ", NULL,", resulting in something like this:

```
INSERT INTO blah (meh1, meh2, meh3, meh4, meh5, meh6) VALUES (14, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 5)
```

But in the end, what I get is...

```
INSERT INTO blah (meh1, meh2, meh3, meh4, meh5, meh6) VALUES (14, NULL, '', NULL, '', 5)
```

Does any of you know why this happens and how to solve it?

I have made a workaround by using 2 SUBSTITUTEs, but it feels sloppy.

If you want to test this yourselves with something cleaner, try this:

Original cell content:

```
a, a, a, a, a, a, a
```

Substitute function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(*cell*;", a,";", B,")
```

And this is what you will get:

```
a, B, a, B, a, B, a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, I got this solved by omitting the first comma in the search pattern.

This is, instead of looking for ", ," I searched for " ," and it worked fine.

In this case, there was no other way that a " ," would appear in the text, so I'm going with that.